# How to clone the XML content to .tmp file in Java?

Tags: java, xml, temporary-files

I've tried to copy the XML file and name it as `.tmp` file, but I am missing the XML file in the folder. I need both XML and `.tmp` file in same folder after cloning.

```java
File file3  = new File("C:\\Users\\sensor_2017-02-09_16-59-51.xml");
File file4 = new File("C:\\Users\\sensor_2017-02-09_16-59-51.tmp");
boolean successs = file3.renameTo(file4);
```

Comment: You're calling `renameTo` - that's going to *rename* a flie, not copy it. Use `Files.copy` to copy a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a static [copy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...)) method (Files class required and since java7)

```
Path source = Paths.get("C:\\SomePath\\__foo.xml");
Path destination = Paths.get("C:\\SomePath\\__foo.tmp");

Files.copy(source, destination, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```